# Spring Security Login Captcha integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, captcha

I have integrated a Captcha plugin on Spring MVC Security. The problem is that even if i have a bad captcha but good credentials it will login but show me bad captcha.

I think my problem is in the spring-security file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jtabuleiros/play/*" access="authenticated" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/details" access="hasRole('ROLE_CONCORRENTE')" />


        <custom-filter ref="captchaCaptureFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
        <custom-filter ref="captchaVerifierFilter" after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>


        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>


<!--    <authentication-manager> -->
<!--        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" > -->
<!--            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />     -->
<!--        </authentication-provider> -->
<!--    </authentication-manager> -->


    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"
        class="com.setelog.spring.service.CustomUserDetailsService">
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="select * from users where username = ?"/>
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="select username, role from user_roles where username =?" />
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsDao" class="com.setelog.spring.dao.UserDetailsDaoImpl" >
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>


    <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider"
        class="com.setelog.spring.handler.LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="userDetailsDao" ref="userDetailsDao" />
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />

    </beans:bean>

    <!-- For capturing CAPTCHA fields -->
 <beans:bean id="captchaCaptureFilter" class="com.setelog.spring.businessrules.CaptchaCaptureFilter" />

 <!-- For verifying CAPTCHA fields -->
 <!-- Private key is assigned by the reCATPCHA service -->
 <beans:bean id="captchaVerifierFilter" class="com.setelog.spring.businessrules.CaptchaVerifierFilter">

 <beans:property name="useProxy" value="false"/>
 <beans:property name="proxyPort" value=""/>
 <beans:property name="failureUrl" value="/login?error"/>
 <beans:property name="captchaCaptureFilter" ref="captchaCaptureFilter"/>
 <beans:property name="privateKey" value="6LeTVQcTAAAAAI_NiPSYXAix-OKYp4KcC0aQ5ce2"/>

 </beans:bean>


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Any help suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: http://webdesignledger.com/tips/why-you-should-stop-using-captchas

Comment: @OhadR I appreciate your suggestion but still i would prefer a solution to my problem rather than an alternative

Comment: What does your captchaVerifierFilter do in case of a bad captcha ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by redirecting to the logout page whenever the captcha is wrong. And my login page is also my logout.